# Error with migration to OCI with ZDM

Tags: oracle

I am migrating three on premise databases to OCI with the ZDM tool. The three instances are INS1, INS2 and INS3.

With the INS1 and INS2 instances I have had no problems, the migration finishes correctly. However, the INS3 instance always fails at the same step: "ZDM_RESTORE_TGT ............... FAILED". If I set the EVAL option, it finishes correctly.

The only difference between the INS3 instance and the other two is that the ASM is divided in several folders (DATA, DATA2, FRA, LOB and SYSTEM), while INS1/INS2 everything is divided between DATA and FRA.

Is there any parameter where I have to specify to migrate the whole ASM structure? It occurs to me that it tries to mount the database to start the data reconstruction but the spfile is in another folder than DATA and that's why it doesn't lift.

The error observed in the ZDM is this:

```
auxpasfuat: 2023-06-03T16:37:52.700Z : Restoring data files ...
####################################################################
PRGO-4086 : failed to query the "COUNT(*)" details from the view "V$BACKUP_PIECE" for database "zdm_aux_FSRBMUAT"
```

And this one in the migration log:

```
[jobid-446][2023-06-03T16:37:16Z][mZDM_Queries.pm:597]:[DEBUG] Output is : ORA-01507: database not mounted

 ORACLE instance shut down.

[jobid-446][2023-06-03T16:37:16Z][mZDM_Utils.pm:4500]:[DEBUG] Reporting status:
```